# ItemUpdated event receiver will always get fired inside my enterprise wiki site collection

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, feature, wiki

I added a new ItemUpdated Event Receiver inside my enterprise wiki site collection inside sharepoint server 2013. and i defined the following:-

1. event reciever will get fired when and item was updated.
2. it should fire on "Wiki Pages library".
3. here is the generated element.xml file:-

> ```
>   <Receivers ListTemplateId="119">
>       <Receiver>
>         <Name>EventReceiver1ItemUpdated</Name>
>         <Type>ItemUpdated</Type>
>         <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
>         <Class>UpdateWikiPageTitleandTerm.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1</Class>
>         <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
>       </Receiver>
>   </Receivers>
> </Elements>
> ```

4. the scope of the event receiver is "Web".

now when i edit a wiki page the event receiver will fire correctly, but also if i upload a new image inside the images library and then i edit the images properties the event receiver will get fired, also when i upload a new document inside the document library and then i edit it properties the event receiver will get fire... so not sure why the event receiver is not only firing on "Wiki Pages libraries" ?

Comment: Not sure why you get that behaviour, have you tried with `ListUrl="SitePages"` instead of `ListTemplateId`?

Comment: Try with specific list instead of ListTemplateID. Eg <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Sample">

Comment: @RobertLindgren you know using listurl will not extend well if i am going to use the same event receiver on multiple libraries and multiple sites...

Comment: @Arun listtempleteid is the most extensible option as i can use the same event receiver on multiple sites and lists...

Comment: @RobertLindgren can you advice further on this?? what could be causing this problem ? and is it happening at your end also ?